# Android encoding in all project

Tags: android, xml, utf-8

I've this string in strings.xml file, the problem begins when I compile the code, in the screen the "¡" (in spanish it's used for open the exclamations points) in the screen just can see � symbol. All my files are utf8 encoded.

Few days works, but the project has a problem and I reimported the project in other Eclipse workspace, there started the problem

strings.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
        <string name="aguarda">¡Aguarda!</string>`

[image]

In the screen
�Aguarda!

Comment: try making the string \a1, it is a special character in utf-8

Comment: It's **\u00a1**, in Unicode

Comment: few days works, but the project has a problem and I reimported the project in other Eclipse workspace, there started the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I change the project codification to "MacRoman" and works again. Really don't know why but if you have this problem can help you.